# Efficient creation of multidimensional array from a list of strings requiring .split(',')

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to push a simple calculation currently in a `for` loop into a `numpy` array. In this case it's a calculation on a list of strings in the form:

`strings = ['12,34', '56,78'...]`

I need to:

1. Split the strings by the comma delimiter and produce two ints e.g.
   `strings = [[12, 34], [56, 78]...]`
2. Filter this nested list to only only those members that meet some arbitrary criteria e.g. both numbers in the sublist fall within a particular range.

I'm trying to get familiar with the `numpy` library but I've been unable to leverage the improved calculation speed without an increased overhead in processing the initial list. For example, my instinct was to do the `split()` and `int()` conversion in Python prior to creating the array but this ends up being more expensive than a simple `for` loop.

Beyond that, I can't seem to piece together the various `numpy` operations required to do this in an array created from the initial list. Is there a sane way to do this or is it a lost cause for things like this where the array is only used once?

Note: There is an older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938809/instantiate-two-2d-numpy-arrays-from-a-list-of-strings) that suggests the string operations should be done in Python but it doesn't compare runtimes and also might now be out of date.

Comparison of my attempts:

```
import random
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

raw_locs = [str(random.randint(1,100)) + ',' + str(random.randint(1,100)) 
            for x in xrange(100000)]

if __name__ =='__main__':

    # Python approach
    start1 = dt.datetime.now()
    results = []
    for point in raw_locs:
        lon, lat = point.split(",")
        lat = int(lat)
        lon = int(lon)
        if 0 <= lon <= 50 and 50 <= lat <= 100:
            results.append(point)
    end1 = dt.datetime.now()

    # Python list comprehension prior to numpy array
    start2 = dt.datetime.now()
    converted_list = [map(int, item.split(',')) for item in raw_locs]
    end2 = dt.datetime.now()

    # List comprehension + numpy array creation
    start3 = dt.datetime.now()
    arr = np.array([map(int, item.split(',')) for item in raw_locs])
    end3 = dt.datetime.now()

    start4 = dt.datetime.now()   
    results2 = arr[((0 <= arr[:,0]) & (arr[:,0] <= 50) 
                    & (50 <= arr[:,1]) & (arr[:,1] <= 100))]
    end4 = dt.datetime.now()

    # Print results
    print "Pure python for whole solution took:                {}".format(end1 - start1)
    print "Just python list comprehension prior to array took: {}".format(end2 - start2)
    print "Comprehension + array creation took:                {}".format(end3 - start3)
    print "Numpy actual calculation took:                      {}".format(end4 - start4)
    print "Total numpy time:                                   {}".format(end4 - start3)
```

Comment: I believe you might have an XY problem. Are you really only converting to this string representation to avoid a for loop somehow? Or is the format given? A list of strings is not a very convenient starting point for numpy. Joining those together with commas and parsing that could be faster.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You could well be right. It was actually inspired by another question on here a few hours ago. Someone was trying to process several trillion such items and I frequently do similar operations, so I was curious about whether you could ever overcome the array creation overhead in places where this would really matter (the `if` check takes around 26% of the runtime by line profiling so could be orders of magnitude faster)

Comment: Also, judging by wallclock time might not be the best metric, `timeit` might be more useful. Let me see what it shows on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think your timings would be more precise if you were using something like the `timeit` module, I think the largest problem is that you're parsing a list of strings. Numpy's built-in methods work well with either. Note that in your numpy case the input to `np.array()` is a list comp with other stuff inside.

Here's my suggestion: join your list of strings with commas to get a single comma-separated string, parse it with `numpy.fromstring`, then reshape the result to have two columns:

```
arr = np.fromstring(','.join(raw_locs),sep=',').reshape(-1,2)
```

Timings with the above added on my laptop:

```
Pure python for whole solution took:                0:00:00.128965
Just python list comprehension prior to array took: 0:00:00.156092
Comprehension + array creation took:                0:00:00.186023
Join + fromstring took:                             0:00:00.035040
Numpy actual calculation took:                      0:00:00.001355
Total numpy time:                                   0:00:00.222454
```

Note that the above will create an array of dtype `numpy.float64` by default, even though your inputs are integers. You can manually pass the `dtype=np.int64` keyword argument to `fromstring` if you want to keep your array integer-valued.

Comment: I used `datetime` mostly so I could break down the component parts into a simple MCVE. This is a really neat solution to pull the string operations out of Python, which is the approach I kept stumbling upon on my searches. I will wait to see if anyone else has input but I would think this is the best we can get.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm perfectly fine with waiting for other potential answers, you don't have to mark my answer as accepted:)